# What is CAS in NoSQL and how to use it?

Tags: database, nosql, couchbase

Write operations on Couchbase accept a parameter `cas` (create and set). Also the return result object of any non-data fetching query has `cas` property in it. I Googled a bit and couldn't find a good conceptual article about it.

Could anyone tell me when to use *CAS* and how to do it? What should be the common work-flow of using *CAS*?

My guess is we need to fetch *CAS* for the first write operation and then pass it along with next write. Also we need to update it using result's *CAS*. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

CAS actually stands for *check-and-set*, and is a method of optimistic locking. The CAS value is associated with each document which is updated whenever the document changes - a bit like a revision ID. The intent is that instead of pessimistically locking a document (and the associated lock overhead) you just read it's CAS value, and then only perform the write if the CAS matches.

The general use-case is:

1. Read an existing document, and obtain it's current CAS (`get_with_cas`)
2. Prepare a new value for that document, *assuming no-one else has modified the document* (and hence caused the CAS to change).
3. Write the document using the `check_and_set` operation, providing the CAS value from (1).

Step 3 will only succeed (perform the write) if the document is unchanged between (1) and (3) - i.e. no other user has modified it in the meantime. Typically if (3) does fail you would retry the whole sequence (`get_with_cas`, modify, `check_and_set`).

There's a much more detailed description of check-and-set in the Couchbase Developer Guide under [Concurrent Document Mutations](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.1/developer-guide/cas-concurrency.html).